Who Bears the Burden of Proof Regarding Free Will: Advocates or Skeptics
Debates on free will often raise the question of evidence: who will have the best evidence? However, before discussing evidence, I would like to know who bears this responsibility in philosophical and scientific discussions. Should it be borne by proponents asserting the existence of free will or by skeptics challenging its validity, given advances in neuroscience and psychology?

I don't debate with determinismists... they are so predictable.

There have been other questions about burden of proof. Why should the burden be different for this than any other issue?

Whoever makes any claim bears the burdern of proof of that claim.

Honestly most of the answers here are absolute waffle. Here's the actual answer. Both of them. Burden of proof applies if you are making a claim. That's it. Sometimes people will emphasise the point more by saying 'positive claim' but that doesn't actually mean anything different in this context.
People are used to thinking only one side has burden of proof from arguments where someone is trying to convince the other party of their claim and the other party is not believing. The important thing is that these situations only arise if the other party PURELY lacks belief in the claim, NOT if they also start arguing the opposite or for an alternative.
The most widespread example I think people will have picked up on this is arguments on the existence of God. The atheist shouldn't be expected to 'prove' God isn't real because they're not claiming anything, they're simply currently unconvinced by the claims of others. However, if this atheist then made the claim that God ISN'T real (not just that they currently don't believe it is), they would also have a separate burden of proof for this claim. You can flip the situation by removing the believer's claim. If a believer is minding their own business and someone just starts claiming to them that God isn't real, they should not be expected to prove that God is real, lest the atheists claim be treated as correct.
To finalise the point, an advocate for the existence of free will has the burden of proving their claim. The skeptic also has the burden of proving their claim. If one of these sides dropped their claim and was simply considering and critiquing the claim of the other side, THEN there would be one side whom had the burden of proof (who would be whichever side was making the claim).

My answer explains how that justification requirement already was met in the strongest way we can by free will based on pragmatic utility. Ted Wrigley’s answer points out how little justification that determinists provide.

If you are going to posit equivalence between someone arguing for the existence of a thing, and someone arguing that we should assume it doesn't exist until evidence is provided, you are going to waste an awful lot of time arguing against absurdities.  In the context of free will, we can be reasonably certain that the vast majority of the 'stuff' in the universe doesn't have it.  Therefore, the claim that humans do (uniquely, or nearly so) is the extraordinary claim, and should carry the burden of proof, IMHO.

@Paul I don't posit that equivalence. In fact you should find it clear that I was pointing out the crucial distinction between those 2 things as the decider of whether a party has burden of proof or not. Talking about the ordinary-ness of claims is something for your argument, not for meta discussions. It doesn't effect burden of proof. If you're claiming something, acting as if it were true without you proving it is unreasonable. Hence burden of proof. It's no more complex than that before it becomes inaccurate.

It is best to not believe anything, make people prove it.

The Burden of Proof isn't an absolute property. There's no experiment you can perform on a person, a brain, or a position to show that that thing has the burden of proof.
The Burden of Proof is a social construct. Consider that in physics, there's a concept of inertia: objects at rest stay at rest, objects in motion stay in motion. In the realm of ideas and beliefs, the same concept is there: we have inertia with respect to our ideas. Just like it takes work to change the motion of an object, it takes work to change the beliefs of a person or of a group of people.
The Burden of Proof is a way of expressing the need for that work. If you want me to change my beliefs, you must put in some work to overcome my inertia.
If you don't have any desire to change someone's beliefs, then you also have no burden.

Human beings work on a presumption of free will; few people (outside of certain psychological disorders) believe they have absolutely no control over their actions moment to moment. Therefore the burden of proof lies with the determinists.
This is exactly the same as the belief that the sun rises and sets. This is how the world presents itself to direct sensory experience, and so the burden of proof fell on physicists to show that (in fact) the Earth rotates giving the appearance of the sun rising and setting. It may be that the presumption of free will is wrong, but until determinism is demonstrated through some empirical research we must (perforce) go with the way our minds present to us, as having a capacity for free will.
It's ridiculously easy to assert a counterfactual; every precocious adolescent does it with abandon. But counterfactuals are only as useful as the evidence supporting them. The argument against free will is (currently) a purely theoretical counterfactual that flies against what seems to us to be true. I won't quibble with the framework, but it lacks any connective tissue.

I like the first two paragraphs. A general discussion of counterfactuals causes me some concern. I think counterfactuals are inherent in the effort to reason. In science the ideal case, or in law the comparative case, is a counterfactual case. Galileo, for example, uses counterfactual reasoning to develop our best concept of motion (force changes momentum). He argues that in the absence of resistance, for example, a rock and a feather would fall at the same rate of acceleration; or a body projected at initial speed along a horizontal plane continues forever at that speed in a straight line.

@SystemTheory: Counterfactuals are marvelous as a starting point. We have to be able to imagine what doesn't seem to be if we want to understand what is. But they are just too easy; we can dredge up counterfactuals almost as fast as we can speak (e.g., the earth is flat, and the moon landing was faked, …). We have to privilege what appears to be true on face value, so that counterfactual propositions have to demonstrate some traction before being taken seriously. Otherwise we just get swamped with wild claims.

Having control over your actions does not imply free will, as that control could be utilized in a way that is not free. This becomes cleat when you try to answer the question "Why do people will what they will?"

@rus9384: That would be a speculative counterfactual. What appears to us is that we have free control over our own actions. That appearance may be wrong, but the burden is on those who must demonstrate that it is wrong. The minute you use the phrase 'could be' you assign yourself the task of turning that 'could be' into an 'is'.

More so I challenge the idea that "people have free will" is an intuitive notion. Though, as usual, this is probably about semantics of the word "free". In my understanding, things like desire to live make will inherently unfree.

@rus9384: I think you're conflating the philosophical concept of 'free will' with the political concept of 'liberty'.

"few people (outside of certain psychological disorders) believe they have absolutely no control over their actions moment to moment." Indeed, but it is not unreasonable for curious people to ask what justification exists for this belief that they themselves may hold. It is one thing to say that those who assert that free will is an illusion have the burden of proof, but if one were to take it further - to say that those who merely question free will bear a burden of proof - then that would (IMHO) be a matter of avoiding rather than addressing the question.

Another question: Why do counterfactuals require free will? Counterfactuals just lie within the domain of imagination, in that they are not very different from fiction. And an ability to make up things does not seem to be an argument for existence of free will.

@sdenham: Again, I have no issue with people asking questions; questions are good. But speaking scientifically we have to assert the answer that best conforms to experience. We experience ourselves as having free will; we have no evidence or experience that we are deterministic; thus, we ought to hold the prior view until new evidence shows otherwise.

@rus9384: Counterfactuals themselves don't require free will. But the ability to imagine otherwise is fundamental to the ability to do otherwise. If someone commits murder, we have to be able to say: "there were other courses of action that did not involve murder". Otherwise we can't say it's wrong. If the only possible thing that person could do was kill, then s'he did not make a moral choice, and if s'he's not making a moral choice then there's no wrong involved. animals can't commit murder because they can't make moral choices.

I am not taking issue with your answer to the question as posed, but I am concerned that the question and answer combined could be seen by some third parties as justification for dismissing the question. In your sun rise/set example, I think we agree that it was a good thing that some people did question something that was just obvious to everyone, even though their knowledge was, at first, insufficient to carry the burden of proof... I don't think this is a pedantic issue, as burden-of-proof arguments are sometimes the last resort of those who do not want awkward questions asked.

@sdenham: I get your point, but I also understand the other side of that coin. Questions are never innocuous, and not always irreproachable. A question is (by definition) an assault on authority — a power ploy — and far too many people are more interested in assaulting power than in being rational. Sometimes questions should be dismissed because they cast shade, not light.

@sdenham: to be frank, There is a contingent of hard-line atheists who frequently question free will not because they believe themselves to be deterministic or care about the philosophical debate, but because they think 'free will' gives religious advocates traction. They want to defang religious arguments, and throw out 'free will' because it vaguely smacks of 'soul'. Wherever social power comes into play we'll find philosophically bad actors on every side…

We could say murder is wrong just as we can say a proposed solution to some problem is wrong, without relying on the idea that it was possible for the agent to do otherwise. Maybe, it was not possible for them to solve a mathematical test problem correctly, but that does not mean they were not wrong. It is possible to assert that wrongness does not even rely on what a particular agent could do, but relies on what an arbitrary agent in their place could do. Which is a counterfactual, but not the one that relies on free will.

@rus9384: That's not how moral agency works, but… I don't really want to extend this further. Not the right place for it.

@TedWrigley Ah, I had a feeling from the beginning that there was a specific agenda behind this question.

"Human beings work on a presumption of free will" - Indeed, but the problem is that philosophers have made a muddle of this. The problem is what does that sentence actually mean - what is the 'free will' that we actually care about - what does it mean to make choices?

@mudskipper: Don't make a muddle of what isn't muddle. If I hand you an apple you can eat it, or put it down, or throw it at me, or carve it like a pumpkin. You won't feel like you have to do one thing or the other or the other; there's no obvious logical necessity or mechanical proscription that draws you to this or that. At face value, the only possible explanation you can give for whichever action you ultimately take is that you chose to do that as an act of free will. There's nothing else you can say. You don't have to explain exactly what it is or means; it's an apparent fact.

@mudskipper: Think of it this way. If a big red ball suddenly appeared two feet in front of you and fell to the ground, you would have a lot of questions. But the one thing you can't have questions about is that it happened. You don't know why it happened, you don't know how it happened, you may not be willing to believe that the happening is actually what you think it is. But on face value it's a fact that it happened, and you can't get around that. So, a hundred times a day you make what look like choices; that's factual. Explain it away if you can, but don't deny the fact.

@TedWrigley - "An act of free will" is not something simple like "receiving an apple".

@mudskipper: The act of free will isn't receiving the apple. The act of free will is doing something with the apple you receive.

How is it "an act of free will" if I simply, without thinking further about it, eat the apple? Seriously (really, seriously), I do not know what you're talking about here... (But this is all besides the point and not relevant for the OPs question.)

@mudskipper: Sigh… I wish you'd have read my posts with more attention. I said that it appears as an act of free will, because free will is the only prima facie explanation for it. Or are you arguing that if I hand you an apple you must (as a matter of ontological necessity) eat it?

@TedWrigley - Sigh in return .... I have no problems with your post. I'm merely saying that "the appearance of free will" is not some simplistic event. It's unclear what this "appearance" is supposed to mean. (Besides, if "free will" is an explanation, then ipso facto it's already not a simple appearance, something that is just given as experience.)

@mudskipper: But that's exactly why I'm sighing. The event itself is simple: You do this or that, believing you could have done something else instead. You understand prima facie that you have made a choice. That understanding might be proven wrong on further analysis — many prima facie understanding get proven wrong — but until it's proven wrong you have an intellectual obligation to accept the prima facie understanding, at least pro tem. Otherwise you're in the unenviable position of the man who calls every house-pet a dog because he doesn't like the idea that cats might exist.

@TedWrigley - And this is exactly why I am sighing too :) There is nothing "prima facie" or simple here. That belief is exactly the muddle that has been caused by several centuries of Western theological and philosophical indoctrination (with few exceptions such as Spinoza). But go ahead, sigh once more, I'll let you have the last word.

@mudskipper: 'Prima facie' means on the face of it, and has nothing to do with theology or philosophy. The first of our prehistoric ancestors who where self-aware thought they could make choices. Heck, even my dog resists when I make her do something she doesn't want to do (an understanding she could do otherwise), and she doesn't even have words. I need to use the words of our philosophical tradition to discuss this, because that's what we have, but I'm using the words to point at a pre-verbal experience, not belaboring a verbal theory. You're making a fundamental mistake.

In dealing with our world, we have developed pragmatic models of a) selfhood, b) agency c) a physical world d) other mind are agents, etc for a large suite of conventional worldview assumptions.  These models are developed in infancy and early childhood, and have the support of empirical pragmatism.
Denials of free will, agency, selfhood, time, consciousness, the external world, mathematics, morality or values, etc therefore have a burden of proof to overturn our cumulative pragmatically evidenced worldview.

From my perspective, both proponents and skeptics of free will should shoulder the responsibility of providing arguments. Proponents must offer compelling evidence demonstrating the compatibility of free will with scientific understandings of determinism, while skeptics should present thorough analyses of scientific findings in neuroscience and psychology that challenge the concept of free will.

Science shows our universe is not deterministic. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/88579/29339

@Dcleve and yet the answers on physics SE (linked as a comment to your answer) dont say that at all...

@JMac That voting on PhysicsSE does not correspond with the physics references I provided or the voting among professional physicists https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00676 is a QC issue for physics SE.

@Dcleve That's like using that philosopher survey to determine the nature of reality.  Those questions ask about physicists opinions, and it doesnt seem like that suggests they are saying "science shows our universe isn't deterministic".  At best I suspect many would say "I believe our universe isn't deterministic based on our current knowledge"; but we really dont understand the science enough to say it "shows" our universe is  non-deterministic.  The science isnt there.

@JMac Do you know what determinism means?  It is that outcomes are knowable and not probabilistic. Neither are true of the “interpretations” endorsed by 97% of the physicists surveyed. Do you accept science/empiricism?  That operates on the acceptance that expert consensus DOES reveal the nature of reality.

@Dcleve But the experts surveyed arent claiming their endorsed interpretations are scientifically proven, the survey isnt supporting the conclusion you are drawing.  To me, the fact that theres no clear consensus on which interpretation is "correct" makes that pretty obvious.  The varied results in the survey show that this is not a topic we've come close to settling.  The science itself supports that local determinism doesnt appear to exist, but that actually doesnt rule out determinism as a whole.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@JMac: See this question and answer on Physics SE. There is experimental evidence for Bell's theorem and the GHZ theorem. The burden of proof is on determinism.

If you have free will, you can decide whether you want to give evidence for your opinion of not. If you don’t have free will, then you don’t have the choice. And of course your opinion may not agree with reality.
So this is a weird question. Most questions about free will are weird.

Only people that have free will can change their opinion, so the burden of proof lies with the determinists.

Determinism does not deny the ability to make decisions or provide evidence for an opinion. On the contrary, it argues that our decisions result from preceding factors and natural laws, but this does not necessarily imply that we cannot make decisions or act according to our will. It's more about determining the influences that shape our choices. Thus, while determinism may challenge the nature of our freedom, it does not mean that we cannot deliberate, choose, and act. Instead, it questions the process of making these "choices".

@LittleEndian Says who? People without free will can change their opinion. Not only can they change their opinions, they have no choice.

If someone's decisions and opinions are entirely a result of preceding events isn't it more like the decisions and opinions are being made for them? Therefore they can't "change their opinion" or "make decisions".

Right. A ball can "roll off a table", but it can't decide or choose or wish to do so.

the burden of proof lies on proving existential claims: if one claims that "there exist (a) non-white swan(s)", then they better exhibit a concrete example
this happens because the logic of empirical matters and observations is not classical, but constructive: even if it's possible to somehow 'prove' ¬∀x¬φ(x), the proof may fail to explicitly provide an object a such that φ(a) holds, and in such cases asserting ∃xφ(x) becomes suspicious; dually, it's not in general possible to "prove non-existence", that is, ¬Exφ(x), for this entails ∀x¬φ(x): even if all swans were in fact (non-non-) white, how could we hope to prove so?
just think about it: if some purported object simply happens to not exist, how exactly would it leave traces or evidence behind it, and of what kind?

@user66697 you mean as in existence of 'moral truths'? sure

@DikranMarsupial people still thought it necessary to directly observe neptune, didn't they? even if we 'predict' some things are likely to exist, in accordance with our best scientific theories, we don't quite believe they do until we go and check, i think

@DikranMarsupial oh, i think you're just reasoning classically: yes, i agree that we cannot exhibit such a star to prove that it exists, so that we cannot 'prove' that it exists, but constructively this is not the same as (and does not entail) arguing that they don't [in fact this example seems a nice illustration as to why we can't expect excluded middle to hold in empirical contexts]

"either there are stars outside the observable universe or there aren't. Exactly what is the alternative?": this assumes excluded middle, and the alternative is basically to forgo 'classical truth' and demand direct proof/evidence either of P or of ¬P in all cases

@DikranMarsupial  "Such "non-classical" reasoning would make science impossible"  That is quite a counter-factual: even just talking of mathematics, that most if not all of mathematics can be developed constructively is rather known.

@DikranMarsupial  But indeed my point is that that does not even hold in maths, let alone more generally: that we need classical reasoning.  Indeed, the scientific method par excellence is about experimental evidence as the criterion of truth, so rather belongs to the "(inductive and) constructive" approach if one has to look at the logic of it.

There are "existence" claims on both sides of the determinism/libertarianism debate. Both sides in some sense claim that something exists, either complete determinism or freedom of will (*).
One can certainly have a preference or disposition towards one position, of the debate, without necessarily having to justify this thesis to anyone. For example, one position might feel more natural  in relation to the other. Certainly, in this sense, we all act under the unmistakable sense of having a degree of agency, and, denying the reality of this feeling is something of an extraordinary claim, in need of similar extraordinary justification.
In spite of the above, we can scrutinize the arguments one may use one way or another.
Determinists have to argue for the actual existence of complete determinism. Partial determinism, which is what science has observed and established up to now, does not mean complete determinism and failure of libertarianism. In fact, partial determinism is required by libertarian position. At most, established partial determinism can be used as a hint for the hypothetical existence of complete determinism that nevertheless needs to be verified.
Libertarians, on the other hand, need to argue for freedom of will. Lack of freedom or freedom that is not willed cannot do. Libertarians can point to established partial determinism as supporting free will by enabling both freedom, and a form of causality, both needed as prerequisites for willing. Furthermore they can point to various, objective and subjective, ways a free action can be attributed as up to the agent. For example, a) stated goals are indeed reached with such high probability that is substantially statistically significant than pure chance and/or complete lack of agency would make possible, or b) the existence of the irreducible sense of willing that cannot simply be explained away as global illusion, etc..
(*) Compatibilism in the sense of fully deterministic (unfree) will is not addressed separately but there are arguments addressing it here or there above. That said, will that does not actually will anything, since everything is bound to happen anyway, is rather a meaningless concept.
So, weight the arguments and feel free to choose..
Some references:

Why the Classical Argument Against Free Will Is a Failure, Mark Balaguer


[..]There’s a big problem with the classical argument against free will. It just assumes that determinism is true. The idea behind the argument seems to be that determinism is just a commonsense truism. But it’s actually not a commonsense truism. One of the main lessons of 20th-century physics is that we can’t know by common sense, or by intuition, that determinism is true. Determinism is a controversial hypothesis about the workings of the physical world. We could only know that it’s true by doing some high-level physics. Moreover — and this is another lesson of 20th-century physics — as of right now, we don’t have any good evidence for determinism. In other words, our best physical theories don’t answer the question of whether determinism is true. [...]Despite the failure of the classical argument, the enemies of free will are undeterred. They still think there’s a powerful argument to be made against free will. In fact, they think there are two such arguments. Both of these arguments can be thought of as attempts to fix the classical argument, but they do this in completely different ways.
[...]The first new-and-improved argument against free will — which is a scientific argument — starts with the observation that it doesn’t matter whether the full-blown hypothesis of determinism is true because it doesn’t matter whether all events are predetermined by prior events. All that matters is whether our decisions are predetermined by prior events. And the central claim of the first new-and-improved argument against free will is that we have good evidence (from studies performed by psychologists and neuroscientists) for thinking that, in fact, our decisions are predetermined by prior events.
The second new-and-improved argument against free will — which is a philosophical argument, not a scientific argument — relies on the claim that it doesn’t matter whether determinism is true because indeterminism is just as incompatible with free will as determinism is. The argument for this is based on the claim that if our decisions aren’t determined, then they aren’t caused by anything, which means that they occur randomly. And the central claim of the second new-and-improved argument against free will is that if our decisions occur randomly, then they just happen to us, and so they’re not the products of our free will.


Why There Are No Good Arguments for Any Interesting Version of Determinism, Mark Balaguer


This paper considers the empirical evidence that we currently have for
various kinds of determinism that might be relevant to the thesis that human beings possess libertarian free will. Libertarianism requires a very strong version of indeterminism, so it can be refuted not just by universal determinism, but by some much weaker theses as well. However, it is argued that at present, we have no good reason to believe even these weak deterministic views and, hence, no good reason — at least from
this quarter — to doubt that we are libertarian free. In particular, the paper responds to various arguments for neural and psychological determinism, arguments based on the work of people like Honderich, Tegmark, Libet, Velmans, Wegner, and Festinger.


An Argument for Libertarian Free Will: Hard Choices Based on either Incomparable or Equally Persuasive Reasons, Randall Firestone


This articles proposes that the best explanation for hard choices,
which are choices made when there are either incomparable options or
equally appeal- ing options, is the presence of libertarian free will;
and that the two main al- ternatives, determinism and random choice,
do not provide us with very compelling explanations. In the case of
determinism, this is because the rea- sons supporting each option do
not dictate or necessitate that we choose that option, and therefore
any decision is necessarily underdetermined by the rea- sons for each
option. Random choice fares no better since any choice made when the
options are incomparable or equally appealing is supported by rea-
sons and therefore is not random at all. As such, we should believe in
free will.


A rationalist argument for libertarian free will, Stylianos Panagiotou


In this thesis, I give an a priori argument in defense of libertarian
free will. I conclude that given certain presuppositions, the ability
to do otherwise is a necessary requirement for substantive
rationality; the ability to think and act in light of reasons.
‘Transcendental’ arguments to the effect that determinism is
inconsistent with rationality are predominantly forwarded in a Kantian
manner. Their incorporation into the framework of critical philosophy
renders the ontological status of their claims problematic; rather
than being claims about how the world really is, they end up being
claims about how the mind must conceive of it. To make their
ontological status more secure, I provide a rationalist framework that
turns them from claims about how the mind must view the world into
claims about the ontology of rational agents. In the first chapter, I
make some preliminary remarks about reason, reasons and rationality
and argue that an agent’s access to alternative possibilities is a
necessary condition for being under the scope of normative reasons. In
the second chapter, I motivate rationalism about a priori
justification. In the third chapter, I present the rationalist
argument for libertarian free will and defend it against objections.
Several objections rest on a compatibilist understanding of an agent’s
abilities. To undercut them, I devote the fourth chapter, in which I
give a new argument for incompatibilism between free will and
determinism, which I call the situatedness argument for
incompatibilism. If the presuppositions of the thesis are granted and
the situatedness argument works, then we may be justified in thinking
that to the extent that we are substantively rational, we are free in
the libertarian sense.


Free will is not a theory or any matter of belief. Free will is a matter of definition. Free will is just a name given to a phenomenon that can be either real or imaginary.
Within the framework of one definition there are no advocates or skeptics. The definition tells, whether free will is a real phenomenon or an imaginary one.
In the absence of one "official" definition the debate is about what would be the most appropriate definition for free will. In any case free will exists, we just have to define what it is.
